# Why is a line break (<br />) being added to my image URL?

Tags: wordpress, url, divi

My website is built on WordPress and using the theme Divi. I am writing a new post and using the Divi image module to add images. In the editor the image shows up fine, however when the post is previewed or published, the image doesn't show up. Upon inspection, the URL for the image has a `<br />` in it which is breaking the link to the image.

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Just an update, I contacted Divi support and they suggested it was a server issue and that I should contact my hosting provider. I did, and we did some troubleshooting but didn't figure out the issue. I enabled Safe Mode which disables all plugins, child themes, etc. and the issue was still present. I also tried turning off media optimization, no luck. They elevated my support ticket to advanced support so I will hopefully hear back from them today.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting your image directly with the text editor or a you writing your text separatly ? With divi's page builder you can add an image to a block or widget, and write the text inside separatly.

Comment: I'm using the divi image module [link](https://www.elegantthemes.com/documentation/divi/image/). Once the module is placed it asks me to pick an image from the media gallery. I can use a code module and place the image src there and see what happens.

Comment: If I place a code or text module and use img src then the image shows up without any issue or edited URL. I wonder why this particular post is having trouble with the image module then...

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue - [Divi image module - generates a wrong path of image src](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69624460/1144521).

I also have no solution, but I built a work around until the cause is found and have concrete solution.

```
function change_url_the_content($content){
   $content = preg_replace("/br\%20\//", "", $content );
   return $content;
}

add_filter("the_content", 'change_url_the_content', 9999999);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out! It was a stupid mistake on my end but hopefully this will help someone out in the future.

The reason an additional **br** or **br%20** is being added to the image src, is due to the Site Url and WordPress Address URL in the "General Settings" of the dashboard.

Since I edited this info in phpmyadmin instead of the wordpress dashboard, I accidentally added a line and a space... so frustratingly dumb on my part!

[Correcting the additional BR and space in image src](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITkiA.png)